# How to get last 30 minutes,1 Hour time from the from current time in DART

Tags: datetime, dart

how can I get the last 3 hours time from the current time in DART

I am getting the current time by this

```
DateTime toTime = new DateTime.now();
```

I want to get last last 30minutes before,lastOneHour,lastThreeHour,last 6,last 12,last 24 time from the current time.

I tried doing like this

```
    from = toTime.subtract(new Duration(hours: 0.5)).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    //This is not working
```

I am converting those result to epochtime.

Comment: The hours parameter are of the type int and can therefore not be a float value. Instead use the minutes parameter and set it to 30: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Duration/Duration.html

Answer (score 1):

As @julemand101 pointed out, Duration has its named `hours` parameter as an int. Passing a double will toss an error. Instead, write your code something like this:

```dart
DateTime curTime = new DateTime.now(); //Current local time
DateTime thirtyMinAgo = curTime.subtract(Duration(minutes: 30));
int thirtyMinAgoInMs = thirtyMinAgo.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
return thirtyMinAgoInMs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). Inspired by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). It also takes into account the leap years and how many days there are in each month

To get the last 30 minutes

```
Jiffy.now().subtract(minutes: 30);

// You can also add your DateTime object
Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime.now()).subtract(minutes: 30);
```

To get the last 3 hours

```
Jiffy.now().subtract(hours: 3);
```

You can also get up to months and years

```
var jiffy = Jiffy.now()
    .subtract(minutes: 30, hours: 3, days: 6, months: 2, years: 1);

print(jiffy.dateTime);
// Or you can format it on the go
print(jiffy.format("dd, MMM yyyy"));
print(jiffy.yMMMd);
```

Hope this helped.